# Metadata Query when storing data as array possible?

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, post-meta

Suppose I store all my post meta data in an array like

```
$meta = array(
    'img' => '',
    'caption' => ''
);

update_post_meta($post->ID, 'theme_banner', $meta);
```

Can I query posts where the img is filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: NO!

I've asked a similar question before [mysql order by serialized data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234057/mysql-order-by-serialized-data)? 
 and the answer i got is:

> The only possible case when serialized
>   data is acceptable is when you don't
>   need to search , filter or order by through
>   that data. In all other cases - store
>   your data as a separated fields.